Pyautocad Fill a figure
Does anyone know how I can fill an amorphous figure with rectangles of the same size without them leaving the figure or automatically cutting them with pyautocad? As seen in the image
I tried pyautogui but it doesnt work

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
